# Line graph over Bar Chart ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

I am trying to plot `line graph` over the `bar plot` with `double-y-axis` using `ggplot2`.

Below is the example data and code for bar chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame("groups" = c('AA','BB','CC', 'AA','BB','CC', 'AA','BB','CC'), 
                   "something" = c('aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccccc', 'dddddddd', 'eeeeeee', 'ffffffff', 'gggggggggg', 'hhhhhhhhh', 'iiiiiiiii'),
               "value1" = c(1.1, 2.4, 3.5, 5, 4.1, 3, 2.5, 1.4, 4.5),
               "value2" = c(2, 25, 10, 4, 15, 5, 3, 4, 8))
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = something,
                   y = value1,
                   fill = groups)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",  position = "dodge") + 
  xlab("something") + ylab("groups") + labs(fill = "groups") +
  theme_bw() + theme(aspect.ratio = 2/1,
                 axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
                 axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold"),
                 axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.2, hjust=1)) + coord_equal(1/0.2)
```

I am trying to add the `line` to the above `bar chart`. However, the `scale` on both sides of `y-axis` show same.

```
p1 + geom_line(aes(x = something, y = value2), size = 1, color="red", group = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Count")) +
  geom_point(aes(x = something, y = value2), size = 1, color="blue", group = 1) +
   theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

When I tried to manipulate `y` value as shown in [biostats](https://biostats.w.uib.no/overlaying-a-line-plot-and-a-column-plot/). However, I am still not getting the correct `line`, `bars` and `values`.

```
p1 + geom_line(aes(x = something, y = 0.1*value2), size = 1, color="red", group = 1) +
   scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./0.1, name = "Count")) +
   geom_point(aes(x = something, y = 0.1*value2), size = 1, color="blue", group = 1) +
   theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

I would like to have correct `line` and `bar` plots for each of the corresponding `axis`.

Comment: What's exactly your issue with the plot? To me your plot and the sec axis looks fine. The sec axis ranges from 0 to 50 and shows the correct scale for `value2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these changes on your plot. It looks like an issue with scaling factor for the variables:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
data <- data.frame("groups" = c('AA','BB','CC', 'AA','BB','CC', 'AA','BB','CC'), 
                   "something" = c('aaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccccc', 'dddddddd', 'eeeeeee', 'ffffffff', 'gggggggggg', 'hhhhhhhhh', 'iiiiiiiii'),
                   "value1" = c(1.1, 2.4, 3.5, 5, 4.1, 3, 2.5, 1.4, 4.5),
                   "value2" = c(2, 25, 10, 4, 15, 5, 3, 4, 8))
#Scale factor
sf <- max(data$value1)/max(data$value2)
#Plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = something,
                       y = value1,
                       fill = groups)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",  position = "dodge") + 
  xlab("something") + ylab("groups") + labs(fill = "groups") +
  theme_bw() + theme(aspect.ratio = 2/1,
                     axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
                     axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold"),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.2, hjust=1)) + 
  coord_equal(1/sf)+
  geom_line(aes(x = something, y = value2*sf), size = 1, color="red", group = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./sf, name = "Count")) +
  geom_point(aes(x = something, y = value2*sf), size = 1, color="blue", group = 1) +
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

Output:

[image]

The original plot from your code is next:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with introducing a second axis. The first one is more general. Scales on dual axis charts are arbitrary, leading the reader into making potentially false assumptions about the relationship of two measurements.

If you however want to continue with dual axis charts, the second problem is within Ggplot2. `sec.axis()` does not build a completely new axis, it rather transforms/ builds the axis based on the other. In your case the second scale is 5 times larger than the first one, so the second axis needs to be multiplied by 5. In order to adjust the range of the second graph (line plot) we need to divide it by 5.

This code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = something,
                 y = value1,
                 fill = groups)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity",  position = "dodge") + 
        geom_line(aes(x = something, y = value2/5), size = 1, color="red", group = 1) +
        geom_point(aes(x = something, y = value2/5), size = 1, color="blue", group = 1) +
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*5, name = "Count")) +
        scale_x_discrete(labels = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii"), ,
                         guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
        labs(title = "Overlay of bar and lineplot",
             x = "something", 
             y = "groups", 
             fill = "groups") +
        theme_bw() + 
        theme(aspect.ratio = 2/1,
              axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
              axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold"),
              axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
              axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
              axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
              axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

results in this [image: plot]